# Results about Hilbert-Sobolev space with homogeneous boundary condition.

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, reference-request, hilbert-spaces, sobolev-spaces

I am currently reading works about numerical method for solving differential equations. The main setting of the work revolves on the space $H^m_0[0,1]$, which is defined by
$$
H^m_0[0,1]:=\{f\in W^{2,m}[0,1]\ |\ f^{(j)}(0)=f^{(j)}(1)=0\ ;\ j=0,1,\dots,m-1\}\ .
$$
It is claimed that $\|u\|_m:=\sqrt{\langle u,u \rangle_m}$ is indeed a norm on $H^m_0[0,1]$, where $\langle u,v \rangle_m$ is defined by
$$
\langle u,v \rangle_m:=\int^1_0u^{(m)}(t)v^{(m)}(t)dt
$$
(our field is Real). I want to know the relation between this norm and the usual norm induced by
$$
\langle u,v \rangle:=\sum_{j=0}^m\left(\int^1_0u^{(j)}(t)v^{(j)}(t)dt\right)\ .
$$
Where can I read more about the Sobolev space with homogeneous boundary condition (I don't know if it's normally called by this name)? Is there an introductory article about this and related topics?

Any help would be highly appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: Both norms are equivalent. This follows from applying Friedrichs inequality. See also Bramble-Hilbert lemma and Poincare's inequality.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Seeing you remind me of a question I asked quite some time ago that I've forgotten to accept your answer. Can you perhaps  recommend me an article or a book related to these Sobolev stuff? I've just started learning about them.

Comment: http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02559531 , 
The books of Evans  (general theory of PDEs), S. Brenner, R. Scott, Dietrich Braess (focused on numerical methods and more precisely Finite Element Method for PDEs) should be helpful, although you will not find exactly what you are asking. Also try to search for the so called Sobolev norm equivalence theorem. I tried, but couldn't find it.

Comment: @Svetoslav It's OK. I think the general theory and basic knowledge would benefit me more than the specific thing I was asking.

Comment: @Svetoslav I am sorry to bother you, but have you heard about any similar results when the boundary condition is only $f(0)=0$ but $f(1)$ is not required to be $0$? I believe that it is enough in order that $\langle u,v \rangle := \int_0^1 u'(t)v'(t) dt$ be an inner product.

Comment: Yes, it is again an inner product  over the linear space $C^1([0,1])$ with zero boundary condition at $x=0$: linearity is obvious, and for the positive definiteness note that $\int\limits_{0}^{1}{u'^2(x)dx}=0\Rightarrow u'=0\Rightarrow u=0$, because $u\in C^1$ and $u(0)=0$. Moreover, this inner product induces equivalent norm to the one, induced by $\langle u,v\rangle=\int\limits_{0}^{1}{uv+u'v'}$ on the same space $C^1([0,1])$ with zero boundary condition at $x=0$ (both norms are also equivalent for zero BC at both ends, and also if the BC is only at the right end).

Comment: To see why they are equivalent ( I show it for either zero BC at both ends, or for zero BC at left end) note that one direction of the equivalence inequality is obvious. For the other, write $u(x)=u(0)+\int\limits_{0}^{x}{u'(t)dt}=\int\limits_{0}^{x}{u'(t)dt}$. Now square both sides and apply Cauchy Schwartz: $|u(x)|^2\leq x\int\limits_{0}^{x}{(u'(t))^2dt}\leq \int\limits_{0}^{1}{(u'(t))^2dt}$. Finally, integrate both sides to get $\int\limits_{0}^{1}{u(x)^2dx}\leq\int\limits_{0}^{1}{(u'(x))^2dx}$.

Comment: Also, note that because both norms are equivalent, after complition you get the same space (the Sobolev spaces $H_0^1([0,1])=\{u\in L^2([0,1])\,:\, u'\in L^2([0,1])\,and\,u(0)=0\}=\{u\in AC([0,1])\,:\, u(0)=0\}$. ) Analogously, if you make a complition of the space $C^1([0,1])$ with zero BC at both ends, you get the same space (the Sobolev space $H_0^1([0,1])=\{u\in L^2([0,1])\,:\, u'\in L^2([0,1])\,and\,u(0)=u(1)=0\}=\{u\in AC([0,1])\,:\, u(0)=u(1)=0\}$ - here I denoted it the same way like the previous ).

Comment: I forgot to mention the fantastic book of  M. Renardy and R. Rogers "An introduction to partial differential equations"

Comment: I'd really love it if you'd put together your comments into an answer so that I could accept it.